# Im trying to parse a variable in fwrite and it isn't liking my double quotes

Tags: php

Im trying to write whats in the variable $recid but its throwing an error on line 13 i think it has to do with my double quotes and single quotes I'm not entirely sure i did it correctly, i get confused with the single and double quotes

This is the variable i want to write $imageuploadphp but i want the variable within in it $businessname to equal $recid which is outside the variable

```
$recid = $_POST['recid'];
$username = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ownername = $_POST['ownername'];

$imageuploadphp = " <?php if(!empty($_FILES[\"file\"]))
{

foreach ($_FILES[\"file\"][\"name\"] as $key => $name) 
{
if($_FILES[\"file\"][\"error\"][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES[\"file\"]   
[\"tmp_name\"][$key], \"files/{$name}\"))
{

    $businessname = \"{$recid}\";
    echo $businessname;

  $uploaded[] = $name;

}
}


}

?>";
```

This is the php code that is f writing

```
if( $fp = fopen("Business_Pages/" . $filename . "/" . $filename . ".php", "w") )
{
fwrite($fp, $imageuploadphp);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: $businessname = $filename; this should do the work as well,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`NOWDOC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax to avoid having to escape quotes at all:

```
$imageuploadphp = <<<'PHP'
<?php if(!empty($_FILES[\"file\"]))
{

...

}

?>
PHP;
```

Comment: $imageuploadphp = <<<PHP <?php if(!empty($_FILES["file"]))
{

  foreach ($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $key => $name) 
  {
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], "files/{$name}"))
    {

     $businessname = "{$recid}";
     echo $businessname;

      $uploaded[] = $name;
      
    }
  }

  
}

?>
PHP;

Comment: @user2872510: There shouldn't be any whitespace after `<<<PHP` and/or before `PHP;`. I can't see those in your comment, so can you Pastebin the code?

Comment: @AmalMurali, The above code you posted does show me parse errors :). I think it is with the escaping of `\"file\"`

Comment: how do you paste bin? and i took out the \ and it still gave me errors

Comment: @user2872510: Go to a pastebin site, paste your code, copy the link and comment it here.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL still getting this error using your code @AmalMurali